# returning and extern variable through a function

Tags: c

I'm starting programming a dspic33 from Microchip and i'm having problems when I try to return an extern variable. My code is divided in 3 files, and is something like this:

```
main.c  

#include <stdio.h>           /*printf definition ... */
#include "clock.h"
volatile unsigned long count = 0;

int16_t main(void)
{

clock_init();

 while(1)
{
  if(flag)
   {
    printf("MAIN:count = %lu clock_time %lu",count, clock_time());
    flag = 0;
   }
 }
 return 0;
}
```

---

```
clock.h  

...
extern volatile  unsigned long count;
...
```

---

```
clock.c

#include "clock.h"
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _T1Interrupt(void)
{
 count++;
 flag=1;   
 IFS0bits.T1IF = 0;   
}

unsigned long clock_time(void)   
{
return count;
}
```

The output is something like:

```
MAIN:count = 1 clock_time : 590106798  
MAIN:count = 2 clock_time : 590106798  
MAIN:count = 3 clock_time : 590106798
```

and so on...

I'm wondering why the clock_time() is not returning the correct value of count. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the "correct" value in this case? What made you to conclude that what you see now is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try with a wait between:

```
    printf("MAIN:count = %lu clock_time %lu",count, clock_time());
    wait(1000);
    flag = 0;
```

Maybe the clock is very fast and the units of your variable are too small to represent it. Or probaly the conversion in the printf of the variable type.

Comment: I've tried something like: unsigned long tmp = clock_time();
printf(clock_time()); 
and it solved the problem, probably is the clock that is very fast as you said ;) thank you

Comment: welcome, sometimes happens this kind of problems and  are not easy to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is declared as `clock_time_t` but you are returning `unsigned long`. That is a possible problem.

You might have another function named `clock_time` somewhere in your code? I suggest that because from the code you posted in the question I don't see how it can output what you are seeing. Maybe your system library includes a `clock_time`.

Comment: I've simplified the code to post here, but I've missed that one :p  In my code I've "typedef unsigned long clock_time_t;" so it is not the problem